# there is no package called 'BiocInstaller'

Tags: r, rstudio, bioconductor

Whenever I try to install a new package I'm getting this error:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")  
Warning in install.packages :  
  package ‘BiocInstaller’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2 RC)  
Installing package into ‘/home/hd-master/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)  
trying URL 'http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.13/bioc/src/contrib/BiocInstaller_1.12.0.tar.gz'  
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 13509 bytes (13 Kb)  
opened URL  
==================================================  
downloaded 13 Kb  

Error in library(BiocInstaller) :   
  there is no package called 'BiocInstaller'  
Execution halted
```

Comment: Have you tried opening a new R session and running the command? If that doesn't work, can you post your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Even re-installed R, still having the same problem.

Comment: `R version 3.0.2 RC (2013-09-17 r63944)`  
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.2

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a Bioconductor problem, it works on my R 3.0.2

Comment: What happens if you start with a blank `~/.Rprofile`?

Comment: After removing RStudio is not working. But I'm able to install packages through R console. Any pointers what might be the issue?

Comment: Just guessing at, from the command line, `R --vanilla` and then `install.packages("BiocInstaller", repos="http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.13/bioc")`. Also, `BiocInstaller` is a little special; what about installing a standard R package (you say you have problems when trying to install a new package).

Answer (score 9):

- Install R-3.0.2 (not RC).
- Try starting R as follows: `R --vanilla`
- See if you are pointing to a weird mirror. What is the output of `getOption("repos")`?
- Try this: `install.packages("BiocInstaller", repos="http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.13/bioc")`